# How to start a process when another process starts in Windows?

Tags: windows, batch-file, vbscript, startup

I'm trying to create a way that will check if a certain program is running - and if it is, launch another program.

This is my progress in BAT

```
@ECHO OFF
:LOOP
tasklist /nh /fi "imagename eq steam.exe" | find /i "steam.exe" >nul && START "" "C:\Program Files\TeamSpeak 3 Client\ts3client_win64.exe" || goto :LOOP
```

And I created a VBS that basically starts the BAT at Windows startup (this is only to make sure the batch file runs without a visible console window):

```
Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell" ) 
WshShell.Run chr(34) & "C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\StartUp\if Steam running then TS.bat" & Chr(34), 0 
Set WshShell = Nothing
```

My problem is that doing so, i get a incredibly high CPU usage (20 to 60% with a I5-4670k).

Have i done something wrong? Or can I improve the code anyhow? I was thinking about slowing the time where windows checks for the process (i.e. wait 2 sec then check) but I'm really new to coding and I don't have any idea on how to do so.

I know my English isn't perfect, excuse me.

EDIT: If it helps, my PC is running on Windows 10.

Comment: As another option, I believe the Microsoft Application Compatibility Toolkit can do this for you.

Answer (score 3):

> i get a incredibly high CPU usage

You need to give your computer a break between the checks. The `timeout` command interrupts batch execution for a configurable number of seconds:

```
@echo off
setlocal

set "FIND_STEAM=tasklist /nh /fi "imagename eq steam.exe" ^| find /i "steam.exe" ^> NUL"
set "START_TS=start "C:\Program Files\TeamSpeak 3 Client\ts3client_win64.exe""

:LOOP

timeout 5 > NUL
%FIND_STEAM% && %START_TS% || goto LOOP
```

---

EDIT

Here is bells-and-whistles sophisticated way of reacting to the start and termination of a process in Windows using VBScript.

It works with the [WMI](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa394582(v=vs.85).aspx), a powerful framework that can do all kinds of things in Windows. Here we use it to listen to process creation and process termination events. (listening to events is a lot more efficient than polling all processes every second or so):

```
Option Explicit

Dim WMIService, ProcessNew, ProcessEnd
Dim computer, query, teamspeakPID

' create a WMI service object and ProcessNew / ProcessEnd event sinks
computer = "."
Set WMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:\\" & computer & "\root\CIMV2") 
Set ProcessNew = WScript.CreateObject("WbemScripting.SWbemSink", "ProcessNew_")
Set ProcessEnd = WScript.CreateObject("WbemScripting.SWbemSink", "ProcessEnd_")

' we will be waiting for Win32_Process creation events and notify event sink "ProcessNew"
WMIService.ExecNotificationQueryAsync ProcessNew, _
    "SELECT * FROM __InstanceCreationEvent WITHIN 1 WHERE TargetInstance ISA 'Win32_Process'"

' we will also be waiting for Win32_Process deletion events and notify event sink "ProcessEnd"
WMIService.ExecNotificationQueryAsync ProcessEnd, _
    "SELECT * FROM __InstanceDeletionEvent WITHIN 1 WHERE TargetInstance ISA 'Win32_Process'"

' main loop: nothing to do, we just sit and wait
While True
    Wscript.Sleep(500)
Wend

' function that handles "process created" events
Sub ProcessNew_OnObjectReady(latestEvent, asyncContext)
    Dim process
    If LCase(latestEvent.TargetInstance.Name) = "steam.exe" Then
        ' start TeamSpeak
        Set process = GetObject("winmgmts:Win32_Process")
        process.Create "C:\Program Files\TeamSpeak 3 Client\ts3client_win64.exe", null, null, teamspeakPID
    End If
End Sub

' function that handles "process ended" events
Sub ProcessEnd_OnObjectReady(latestEvent, asyncContext)
    Dim processList, process
    If LCase(latestEvent.TargetInstance.Name) = "steam.exe" Then
        ' kill TeamSpeak (but only the one we started earlier)
        Set processList = WMIService.ExecQuery("SELECT * FROM Win32_Process WHERE Name = 'ts3client_win64.exe' AND ProcessId = " & teamspeakPID)
        For Each process in processList
            process.Terminate()
        Next
    End If
End Sub
```

As an exercise you can try to extend this so that it only starts TS when it's not already running.

Further reading:

- Technet "Doctor Scripto's Script Shop" column

  - [WMI asynchronous event monitoring with VBScript](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee692847.aspx#EIAA)
  - [Out of Sync: The Return of Asynchronous Event Monitoring](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee692849.aspx)
- MSDN

  - [The Win32_Process Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa394372(v=vs.85).aspx)
  - [Create method of the Win32_Process class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa389388(v=vs.85).aspx)
  - [Terminate method of the Win32_Process class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa393907(v=vs.85).aspx)
  - [SWbemServices.ExecNotificationQueryAsync method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa393865(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: As i said before my knowledge of coding is really low (I basicly just started) and I'm trying to not just copy paste codes from others but learn something.
this said, it's the only way i found to run the bat file in background (not opening the CMD) is there a better way maybe?

Comment: It works flawlessy, I just had to add the double "" between start and the directory, I even reduced the timeout time to 1.5 and the performance are perfect, love you mate.
the only thing you could do better is explaining to a noobish like me the changes.
thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure that timeout supports spit-seconds. I'm also looking into extending this answer with another technique, might take me a moment, hang on.

Comment: @XenSide See modified post. It's quite a lot to think about, I guess, but it has several advantages over the batch file.

Comment: wow, that's a lot of informations! Thanks!
I've missed a basic thing tho, will this be a .VBS file being it VBScripting?
EDIT: nwm, Found the answer myself, I'm looking into it, I have a lot of things to learn but it's fun and useful, I like it.

Comment: I tested it, it *should* work as it is. But I haven't installed Steam or TeamSpeak on my PC here, so I used other programs for testing. You can use it as a learning resource in any case. :)